# C - transferring information to a struct (specifically an array of strings)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This seems to be a very simple problem but I can't quite figure out which part is causing it. Basically, I have a struct that just contains an array of strings

```
struct command_stream{
  char **tokens;
 };

typedef struct command_stream *command_stream_t;
command_stream_t test;
```

Then later on, I parse some strings into shorter ones and end up with another array of strings

```
char **words = *array of strings*
```

words contains the correct information I want, I looped through and printed out each element to make sure I wasn't getting a faulty string. So now I just point tokens to words

```
test->tokens = words;
```

But it gives me a segmentation fault. I'm not sure why though. They're both pointers, so unless I'm missing something obvious...

EDIT: The function as a whole has to return a pointer, which is why it was set up like this, which I keep forgetting. But I think I've got it, if I just create a new typedef

```
typedef struct command_stream command_stream_s;
command_stream_s new_command_stream;
```

and just return
    &new_command_stream;
That should work right? Even though new_command_stream itself isn't a pointer.

Comment: Post the complete code, enough to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code excerpt, it seems that you have not declared the struct. You have successfully declared a pointer to the struct `command_stream_t test;` but this pointer does not point to anywhere yet.

You need to allocate memory for your struct in some way and make `test` reference it. For instance:

```
    command_stream_t test = 
        (command_stream_t) malloc(sizeof(struct command_stream));
```

This way you can successfully use:

```
    test->tokens = words;
```

as you intended.

Note that you don't need to use `malloc` to allocate the memory. The pointer can reference a local/global variable as long as it has memory associated to it (N.B. if you use a local var don't use the pointer outside the declaration scope of that var).

Comment: Yes. You cannot use the value of a variable until you assign that variable a value. `test->tokens` uses the value of `test`, but there's no `test=<something>;` anywhere to be found.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Exactly. This is one of the reasons why I prefer not to 'hide' pointers in typedefs. Seeing something like `command_stream_t foo` might induce me to believe that `foo` is a full-fledged var when it's not.

Comment: Oh whoops. It's part of a larger assignment and I kept forgetting that they need us to return a pointer which is why it was set up like that. So if I made like typedef struct command_stream command_stream_s (which isn't a pointer) and just returned &new_command_stream at th end, it should work.

Comment: @user1777900 It depends on whether the pointer has memory associated to it or not. You can't return the address of a local var because when you get out of its declaration scope `&new_command_stream` will point nowhere again. If `new_comman_stream` is static/global then it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct command_stream *command_stream_t;
command_stream_t test;
```

This makes "test" a pointer. There is no memory allocated for the structure.
You need to allocate memory for the structure and make the test pointer point to the block of memory before you can dereference by saying -

```
test->tokens = words;
```

Do this:

```
typedef struct command_stream command_stream_t;
command_stream_t test;

test.tokens = words;
```

The difference is that, command_stream_t is no more a pointer type, it is the actual structure.